# Group Managed Service Account not updating password on server

Tags: windows, active-directory, service-accounts

I've just set up a new gMSA on our domain, everything works fine except now that the password has expired, it will not update on the server. I am getting a logon failure for my services. This isn't a replication issue since it has been about 5 days since it had updated. So far it is happening across all 3 servers it was installed on - all Server 2019.
`Test-ADServiceAccount` returns true.

Comment: Is the account configured per this checklist?  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/getting-started-with-group-managed-service-accounts

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was due to the samAccountName being 16 characters total and the maximum it could be was 15. (15 + $ at end)